# Executing a program on a remote computer over the net

Tags: vnc, reboot, remote-access, teamviewer, remote-execution

I'm looking for a small, free Windows app that will allow me to execute a command line on a remote PC over the net - to start a program or reboot.

The reason is this;  I normally leave TeamViewer running on my machine at work and then remote-desktop from home when I need to check on anything, but I have found that TV is incompatible with something else I occasionally run at work and crashes my system (like - big red button stuff).  So I leave TV off and start it before I go home - if I remember.

I therefore need a lightweight program that runs all the time and will allow me to fire up TV or reboot from home.

I realise one way would be to start TV in a scheduled task at 6pm, but being able to execute a command line to reboot the machine would be useful in general to resurrect a scrambled machine at work.

I could just use something else like VNC but I like TV.  It does the job well and requires the minimum of user interaction to connect to the remote PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, here's a few possible tools that'll help - [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) has a bunch of options including the ability to kill tasks by windows, and you can shutdown with the native shutdown command.

As for starting teamviewer, i'd take a look at using [akira and dropbox](http://lifehacker.com/#!5435397/akira-remotely-controls-computers-using-dropbox) or a ssh server such as [freessh](http://www.freesshd.com/) or [copssh](http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh) and putty (possibly)

Comment: @Geek Maybe I wasn't clear - I'm sitting at my PC at home, and I want to start TV running on my work PC.  I'm not sure nircmd can do the remote part, can it?

Comment: you'd need to use something else to run those things - hence my mention of akira (which will definately do it), and ssh (which might, but would be more secure). You can use shutdown and possibly nircmd with ssh to shutdown or reboot. You could possibly use ssh and definately akira to start teamviewer. Its a two part problem - cli tools to do the job, and a cli remote access method to actually run the task.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks @Geek.  Seems like Akira/Latte will do the job.

Comment: I covered a few bases since i wasn't sure of the exact situation, and with one or two small details with respect to SSH. As always, there's more than one way to skin a hypothetical feline :)